# value isLoggedIn is not a member of object com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate

Tags: java, sbt, play-authenticate

I am currently trying to update my sbt project from scala 2.11.2 to scala 2.12.4. Therefore I had to update my play-authenticate dependency from `"com.feth" % "play-authenticate_2.11" % "0.6.9"` to `"com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.9.0"` and got the following error:
`value isLoggedIn is not a member of object com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate`
The same applies for:
`value getUser is not a member of object com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate`
By the way, I have updated to play 2.6.0 which should be compatible with play-authenticate 0.9.0 ([see](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)).

My library dependencies before:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  ws,
  cache,
  javaEbean,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.181",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.6",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "be.objectify"  %% "deadbolt-java"     % "2.3.3",
  "be.objectify"  %% "deadbolt-scala"     % "2.3.3",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.2.0",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.1.0" % "test",
  "com.nulab-inc" %% "play2-oauth2-provider" % "0.14.0",
  "com.feth" % "play-authenticate_2.11" % "0.6.9",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
  javaCore,
  "com.esotericsoftware.kryo" % "kryo" % "2.23.0",
  "org.zeromq" % "jeromq" % "0.3.5",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.5.0.akka23",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.1.0" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.14"
  )
```

and after:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  ws,
  ehcache,
  //javaEbean,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.181",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.28",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.6.0",
  "be.objectify"  %% "deadbolt-scala"     % "2.6.0",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.2.0",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0",
  "com.nulab-inc" %% "play2-oauth2-provider" % "1.3.0",
  "com.feth" %% "play-authenticate" % "0.9.0",
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.1.0",
  javaCore,
  "com.esotericsoftware.kryo" % "kryo" % "2.23.0",
  "org.zeromq" % "jeromq" % "0.3.5",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.4",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.3"
)
```

Comment: I don't think upgrading from play-authenticate 0.6.9 to 0.9.0 and from play 2.3 to 2.6 in one shot is a good strategy. I suggest to do baby steps. Don't skip minor versions. Try to move from 0.6.9 to 0.7.x, then to 0.8.x and so on. Same with play, akka and jdk. Maybe you can start upgrading to scala 2.12.x first and see what happens. Following that path, it will be easier to evolve the project and fix different errors

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem with this approach is, that with scala 2.12, play-authenticate 0.7.x and 0.8.x are not downloadable (Error downloading com.feth:play-authenticate_2.12:0.7.0).

Comment: My bad. I Didn't check that. Well, start upgrading the rest of the dependencies until you can move to scala 2.12. As I said before. Baby steps will let you evolve easier.

Comment: looks like [play framework 2.7 support scala 2.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-server_2.11/2.7.9) and [akka actor 2.5.31 is the latest version available for scala 2.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.5.32). [play core for scala 2.11 depends on akka akka 2.5.31](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/2.7.9). You could try upgrade on that way. Of course, you need to also upgrade `play-authenticate` and hope the other libraries don't cause any conflict